# Unable to execute FXCop analysis in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-4.0

Executing Sonar (version 4.5.4) analysis on a C# sln using the C# built in plugin (version 4.0).
I've set in the settings the location of the FxCopCmd.exe, but I get the following in the execution:
"All FxCop rules are disabled, skipping its execution"
How do I enable the rules?

Thanks,

Ariel

Comment: Why down vote? Please don't disappoint for new comers. Educate them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

- Login into Sonar as administrator
- Click on 'Rules'and select C#
- Under Repository section search for FxCop and add it (it should show a certain number of rules)
- With C# and FxCop selected, click on 'Bulk Change' or 'Settings icon' (depends on which version of sonar you're running), and select 'Activate in.."
- In the search box that appears, add the sonar profile you want to activate these rules in (e.g. Sonar Way), and select Apply

Comment: For me these setting came by default. No Sure. I'm using 5.1